# Placing text (or a link) on top of an image

Tags: php, html

What i'm basically looking for is a way to place some text, in this case a link, on top of an image in a specific location, preferable with coordinates. I know there's a way to place a link on an image via usemap, but as far as i know it's only possible to make the link into a form, like a rectangle or circle.

I have looked for a way but so far have come up short, i hope there's someone who can help a little.

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/article.php/3480021/Text-Over-Images.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <img src="http://www.example.com/blahblah.jpg">
    <a style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;" herf="http://www.example.com">Some link</a>
</div>
```

You need to contain the link in a element and give it a `position` of `relative` while giving the link element a `position` of `absolute`, and setting `left`,`top`,`bottom`, and/or `right`

Comment: This did the trick, thanks. I was thinking in a whole other way so i thought it was more problematic than it actually is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the image as the background (using css class or style attrib) of the `<div>`or any other block level element  and then have your text on top of that, wont that work? Maybe use `position` to fine tune the text in the div.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this, use markup like the following:

```
<div class="container">

    <img src="image.jpg">

    <span class="some-text">Some Text</span>

</div>
```

Couple that with the following CSS:

```
div.container {
    position: relative;
}

span.some-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

In this example, the `position: absolute;` span containing your text would appear to be positioned in the bottom left of the image (though really, it's in the bottom left of the image's parent container, which is `position: relative;`). Change those positioning values as necessary to suit your needs, e.g. `top: 5%;`, `right: 25px;`, or similar.

You could also do as the previous answer suggested and set your image as the `background-image` of a container element. Either solution works. If you used that solution, however, you would have to define the dimensions of the parent `<div>` container. My answer doesn't require this, as the `<img>` inside of the `<div>` will force the `<div>` to be as large as the `<img>` automatically.

Comment: Thanks, this along with Patrick Evans's answer solved it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure this will help but there is a website that has information about HTML CSS java and asp and some more languages the website is:

http://www.w3schools.com hope this helps